# Having trouble parsing a csv file from the commandline

Tags: awk, regular-expression, csv

I have a CSV file that I've been working on for most of the day and I'm not having any luck getting it parsed properly using a Regex with awk.

awk is not processing the Regex as expected.

Here are the inputs:

- GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.5-p2, GNU MP 6.1.2)
- Regex: `/(\[(.*?)\])|[^,]+/g`
- Sample text `hostname,hostname.domain.com,hostname.domain.com,windows,6.2.9200,1.2.3,location,environment,[role1, role2, role3],[recipe1, recipe2, recipe3],2019-01-10 06:06:31`
- Raw text (before stripping out double-quotes, which I do at a step not listed explicitly in this question):
  `hostname,hostname.domain.com,hostname.domain.com,windows,6.2.9200,1.2.3,location,environment,"[""role1"", ""role2"", ""role3""]","[""recipe1"", ""recipe2"", ""recipe3""]",2019-01-10 06:06:31`

When I run this through [Regexr.com](https://regexr.com), it shows the proper matches:
[image: Screencap from Regexr]

I pipe from cat -> sed -> awk (the sample text above is what comes out of sed) and run the following command (I only want the first 9 fields, which includes the entirety of the first field enclosed in [], but not anything after that):

```
awk '/(\[(.*?)\])|[^,]+/g{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9}'
```

What I'm expecting to see as an output:
`hostname,hostname.domain.com,hostname.domain.com,windows,6.2.9200,1.2.3,location,environment,[role1, role2, role3]`

**NOTE:** The important part about this is treating the field with the roles (between the brackets) as a single field, or at least including all of the roles in the output, but none of the recipes)

What I'm actually getting out is the full line that was fed in.

From playing around with the variables, I found the following field assigments coming out of awk:

- $1 = `hostname,hostname.domain.com,hostname.domain.com,windows,6.2.9200,1.2.3,location,environment,[role1,`
- $2 = `role2,`
- $3 = `role3],[recipe1,`
- $4 = `recipe2,`
- $5 = `recipe3],2019-01-10`
- $6 = `06:06:31`

I've tried using the accepted answer from [This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477652/ignoring-comma-in-field-of-csv-file-with-awk) outright, and I've tried tweaking it to use [] as the delimiters instead of ", and that gets me closer, but it's still not treating the role field as a single field.

Comment: What do you intend for the `g` after the regular expression to mean? This would be a syntax error in an extended regular expression (which `awk` uses).

Comment: Actually, what are you trying to do with the regex generally? Which lines do you want to print?

Comment: I only included the g because Regexr did, in the current state, it doesn't change the output at all.
@terdon - I want it to print all of hte fields up to (and including) the field that contains the 3 roles, but nothing after that

Comment: @Taegost OK, but what is the regex doing? Your print statement already does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `awk` will use whitespace to define fields, which explains why you're getting the output you see. Since you want to use a comma to separate the fields, you need to say so with `-F`:

```
awk -F, '{...}'
```

To have `awk` print comma separated output, you need to set the `OFS` variable:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{...}'
```

The real difficulty here is that you are then trying to treat `[role1, role2, role3]` as a single field, but that's 3 fields. There are commas there, so that will be split into `[role1`, `role2` and `role3]`. If you know there will always be exactly 3 fields there, it's easy:

```
$ awk -F, -vOFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11}' file
hostname,hostname.domain.com,hostname.domain.com,windows,6.2.9200,1.2.3,location,environment,[role1, role2, role3]
```

---

However, based on the raw data you have now added, while a [proper CSV parser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/494021/22222) will always be the better approach, you can still do it in `awk`. Just run this on your original input data:

```
$ awk -F']' -vOFS=, '{gsub(/"/,"");print $1"]"}' file
hostname,hostname.domain.com,hostname.domain.com,windows,6.2.9200,1.2.3,location,environment,[role1, role2, role3]
```

The trick is to use `]` as the field separator and tell `awk` to only print the 1st field. This will print everything up to the first `]`. We then add back the `]` (since that is removed when the fields are built). The `gsub` removes all the quotes.

Comment: That field with the roles and the recipes *are* a single data field, which is the problem.  I stripped out the quotation marks that were in it initially because I couldn't get any Regex pattern to treat it as a single field, but still separate the rest on a comma.  I'll update the question with the raw data, that may help.  It'll take me a few minutes

Comment: @Taegost they might be for csv, but they aren't for awk.

Comment: Correct, which is the entire point of the regex: To separate the fields by a comma, except for the ones that include multiple entries (the role and recipe fields), where everything within the brackets needs to be treated as a single field

Comment: If you're using the same character to delimit data and also as _part_ of the data, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: @Taegost given your input data, you can use the fact that you only want the text until the first `]`. But a dedicated CSV parser is a safer approach.

Comment: @terdon - Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.  It does exactly what I need! 
 Unfortunately, installing 3rd party tools is extremely limited for me (Otherwise that option would be much, much easier for me).  I appreciate you taking the time to help me out with this.

Answer (score 4):

If you're dealing with a complex CSV file - in particular, one whose fields may contain quoted delimiters (in this case, commas) then a proper CSV parser is going to save a lot of headaches e.g. with `csvtool`

```
$ echo 'hostname,hostname.domain.com,hostname.domain.com,windows,6.2.9200,1.2.3,location,environment,"[""role1"", ""role2"", ""role3""]","[""recipe1"", ""recipe2"", ""recipe3""]",2019-01-10 06:06:31' | 
    csvtool col 1-9 -
hostname,hostname.domain.com,hostname.domain.com,windows,6.2.9200,1.2.3,location,environment,"[""role1"", ""role2"", ""role3""]"
```

or (to remove the quotes)

```
$ echo 'hostname,hostname.domain.com,hostname.domain.com,windows,6.2.9200,1.2.3,location,environment,"[""role1"", ""role2"", ""role3""]","[""recipe1"", ""recipe2"", ""recipe3""]",2019-01-10 06:06:31' | 
    csvtool col 1-9 - | tr -d '"'
hostname,hostname.domain.com,hostname.domain.com,windows,6.2.9200,1.2.3,location,environment,[role1, role2, role3]
```

---

If you can't obtain a standalone CSV parser such as `csvtool`, then both Perl and Python have CSV modules e.g.

```
perl -MText::CSV -lpe '
  BEGIN{$p = Text::CSV->new()} 
  $_ = join ",", map { $_ = s/"//gr } ($p->fields())[0..8] if $p->parse($_)
'
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer and is definitely the right way to go.  Unfortunately installing 3rd party tools is locked way down and I don't have Perl or Python (But I do have Ruby, didn't think to try that).  Thank you for taking the time to write this up, in the future this will definitely be my preferred approach!

Comment: @Taegost if you figure out how to do it in Ruby, please add that as an answer!